# RoR validation error translations get titelized

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, translation, rails-activerecord

Finally I was able to get started with RoR I18n translations.

I had hard time translating Activerecord validation errors that show up when there are errors during form filling.

While the translation is OK, the messages are shown titelized, for example:

```
* Parol Va Tasdig'i Bo'sh Bo'lishi Mumkin Emas
* Ism Uzun (Ko'pi Bilan 50 Belgi)
* Email Manzil Xato Kiritilgan
```

**Is there any way to 'capitalize' these messages?** So it should look like:

```
* Parol tasdig'i bo'sh bo'lishi mumkin emas
```

As a note, I suspect that the way I'm doing it has some flaws, for instance, this is the html output of above messages:

```
<li>* <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: uzlt.Parol va tasdig'i bo'sh bo'lishi mumkin emas">Parol Va Tasdig'i Bo'sh Bo'lishi Mumkin Emas</span></li><li>* <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: uzlt.Ism uzun (ko'pi bilan 50 belgi)">Ism Uzun (Ko'pi Bilan 50 Belgi)</span></li><li>* <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: uzlt.Email manzil xato kiritilgan">Email Manzil Xato Kiritilgan</span></li>
<li>* <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: uzlt.Parol bo'sh bo'lishi mumkin emas">Parol Bo'sh Bo'lishi Mumkin Emas</span></li><li>* <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: uzlt.Parol qisqa (minimum 6 belgi)">Parol Qisqa (Minimum 6 Belgi)</span></li><li>* <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: uzlt.Parol tasdig'i bo'sh bo'lishi mumkin emas">Parol Tasdig'i Bo'sh Bo'lishi Mumkin Emas</span></li>
```

As you can see, there are some **translation_missing** strings there.

The following is the piece of Slim that outputs messages:

```
  1 - if object.errors.any?
  2   #error_explanation
  3     .alert.alert-error
  4       #{object.errors.count} dona xato mavjud
  5     ul
  6       - object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
  7         li * #{t(msg)}
  8       end                                                                                                    
  9 end
```

When I queried the msg object type, it gave me ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer name.

Thank you again in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `li` element output to solve the problem:

```
- if object.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    .alert.alert-error
      #{t('messages.error_on_form', count: object.errors.count)}
    ul
      - object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        li == "* #{t(msg).capitalize}"
      end
end
```